# How to measure impedance of sensor's traces?

Tags: impedance, trace, arduino-uno

I'm designing a humidity sensor as a semester project and I want to measure impedance of these traces:

[image: Humidity Sensor's Traces]

I don't have specialized impedance measuring instruments for this.
**As I'm thinking, this should be done using Arduino Uno** i.e Some hardware and a bit of code. Help me find a solution to this.

Comment: How many pF do you expect with/without fingerpad knowing HBM = 100pF for a finger.  Frequency oscillation method with Schmitt inverter. Go research methods.  C = ε0 * εr * A / d

Comment: Do fingerpads only contain capacitance? plus, How to find phase? I researched methods,  most say to use instruments

Comment: I suggest an RC delay race between Cref and Ctouch. going into  two D FF sharing a clock and controlling up/down counts with a time interval , sense and reset .  You can also use resistance but insert 10K for ESD protection.

Comment: If you have a current source DC or better sine @ f then voltage increases with Z.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 ... This makes sense

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 ... Can you make a clear answer based on your above suggestions? So that I can start working on it. Thanks,

Comment: I suggest you do some research https://electronicsforu.com/resources/electronics-components/humidity-sensor-basic-usage-parameter

Comment: Could you use a network analyzer and an SMA connector ? In the same style as when you match an antenna. This should yield the impedance of the track.

Comment: Um! No, I don't have these instruments available

Comment: Better have it coated to prevent fungicides and algae or corrosive growth